# Soap UI: Groovy Script to call an API if the response is true

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am very new to use SoapUI. Writing test cases for my project APIs.

My requirement is to run a groovy script after an API call and if the response text of this API is "true", another API should call.

I found myself stuck to do this. Can anyone guide me to do this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: please read Conditional Flow Groovy from here : [https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/controlling-flow.html](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/controlling-flow.html)

Comment: Do you want to add more details if you still have the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer but forgot to inform over here. I did asserted an script like this in TestStep:

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def responseJson = slurper.parseText(messageExchange.getResponseContent())
assert responseJson instanceof Map
assert responseJson.containsKey('authToken')

def id = "Bearer "+responseJson['authToken']
log.info(id.toString())

testRunner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(context.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite").getTestCaseByName("TestCas"), null)
def tcase = testRunner.testCase
def tstep = tcase.getTestStepByName("TestStep")
testContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(tstep)
runner = tstep.run(testRunner, testContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Little idea for this :

```
def response = context.expand( '${TestRequest1#Response}' )

if ( response == 'true' ) 
{

   testRunner.runTestStepByName( "TestRequest2")
}
```

Disable your first test Step(TestRequest1).